# Drawing multiple lines on canvas with paint with shader cause performance issues

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas

Inside SurfaceView in a separate thread on canvas I draw ~50 bezier curves with `Paint` that previously been set to have gradient like in the following code:

`LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
paint.setShader(gradient);`

Setting shader to paint causes serious performance issues - view starts lagging. But if I just comment out setting shader to paint it works brilliant, so the issue is definitely in the gradient.

Thread code:

```
private class DrawingRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private final MyView surfaceView;

    public DrawingRunnable(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MyView surfaceView) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.surfaceView = surfaceView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {

            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                if (canvas != null) {
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                        surfaceView.drawMyHeavyView(canvas);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Timber.w(e, "Error occurred while drawing surface view");
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Drawing on canvas:

```
protected void drawMyHeavyView(Canvas canvas) {

    for (int index = 0; index < 50; index++) {

        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(x1, y1);

        modifySomeAmplitudeRandomValues(index);

        path.quadTo(x3, amplitude[index], x2, y2);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

You should assume that those unknown params (e.g. x1, y1, x2, etc.) are parts of view business logic and aren't valuable for current duscussion.

Can you please advise what's wrong?

P.S.: I'm not allocating LinearGradient in onDraw or so.

Comment: thread code, full rendering code?

Comment: Added thread code, what do you mean by saying rendering code?

Comment: your rendering method

Comment: Added code that is responsible for drawing on canvas, is that what you meant?

Comment: yes that is what i meant